# Can .txt files be edited in SharePoint 2013 with OWA?

Tags: office-web-apps

Can .txt files created in notepad be edited online using office web apps? is there a code available to view them as word files? I know we can do this for pdf is the same code applicable here too?

Answer (score 2):

View  and Edit is not available  for **.txt**  in Online or Office Web App

Below is the list of the file extensions that are not available for **view** and **edit** in **Word, Excel and Power point**

file extensions not available for View and Edit in Word Online or Word Web App

**.dot, .mht, .mhtml, htm, .html, .odt, .rtf, .txt, .xml, .wps, .wpd**  in **Online** or **Office Web Apps**

file extensions not available for View and Edit in Excel Online or Excel Web App

**.xltx, .xltm, .xlam, .xlm, .xla, .xlt, .xml, .xll, .xlw,ods, .prn, .txt, .csv, .mdb, .mde, .accdb, .accde, .dbc, .igy, .dqy, .rqy, .oqy, .cub, .uxdc, .dbf, .slk, .dif, .xlk, .bak, .xlb**

file extensions not available for View and Edit in PowerPoint Online or PowerPoint Web App

**.pot, .htm, .html, .mht, .mhtml, .txt, .rtf, .wpd, .wps, .ppa, .odp, .thmx**

Please check the below link [Unable to View or Edit Office files by using Office Online or Office Web Apps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028380/unable-to-view-or-edit-office-files-by-using-office-online-or-office-w)